# All items in list are identical?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I some lines of code in order to prep the data to be sorted. In order to do this, I needed each item in the list to be a list. For example, if my list was `[a, b, c, d]`, the list should be become `[[a], [b], [c], [d]]` where a, b, c, and d are integers. My code however returns `[[d], [d], [d], [d]]`:

```
len_of_list = random.randint(8500, 10000)
val_list = range(len_of_list)

list_one = [[-1]]
for index in range(0, len_of_list):
    list_one[0][0] = val_list[index]
    val_list[index] = list_one[0]
print val_list
```

The weirdest thing that happens to the code is that when the second-to-last line is replaced with `val_list[index] = list_one[0][0]`, it returns the correct values just without the `[]`. Thus I assumed that removing the last `[0]` would return the values with the `[]` around them. But what is returned was the last integer in the list originally surrounded by `[]` for *all* values. This shouldn't happen because `list[0][0]` is reset every iteration with `list[0][0] = val_list[index]`.

So why is the list being returned as `[[d], [d], [d], [d]]` instead of `[[a], [b], [c], [d]]`. Of course, the list has at least 8500 unique integers but `d` represents the last value in the list or put simply `d = val_list[len(val_list) - 1]`.

Comment: You keep re-using the same list object, you'd want to create a *copy* instead.

Comment: To extend Martijn's brief answer.  Your outer list has 8500 references to *one* list (which you have repeatedly modified).

Comment: run code on http://pythontutor.com (with shorter list) and you will see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `list_one[0]` in `val_list[index]`. Since `list_one[0]` is a list, `val_list[index]` receives its address, not its value. Therefore, when the value of `list_one[0]` is changed, ie. at every iteration, the value of `val_list[index]` for every `index` is changed as well.

Thus, the final value contained at every index of the list is the last one, `[d]`.

This happens because `list_one[0]` is a list, which is **mutable**.

---

Beyond this fact, your code is not really pythonic. First, you build an empty list of length `len_of_list` by writing `val_list = range(len_of_list)`. While this works in Python 2, it does not in Python 3, because a `range` object is semantically different from a list. Besides, a list should be built by appending or inserting elements, but not by making a long enough empty list and then filling the indices.

Then, you are using complicated code to build your list of list, while the following would have been enough:

```
for index in range(len_of_list):
    val_list[index] = [index]
```

A more basic pythonic way to do the same, with `append`, would be:

```
len_of_list = random.randint(8500, 10000)
val_list = list()

for index in range(len_of_list):
    val_list.append([index])
```

However, the most pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension. If you have `l = [a, b, c, d]`, and you want to have `[[a], [b], [c], [d]]`, the fastes is the following:

```
[[elt] for elt in l]
```

Comment: Nice answer but I still want to know what's wrong with my code

Comment: @PythonMaster I updated my answer. I hope you understand the reason why you're getting this output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[x] for x in myList]
```

Comment: Nice answer but I still want to know what's wrong with my cide